# Live updates in website? (streamerapi)

Tags: web, push

I was in http://finance.yahoo.com/ and checked the europe tab ( markets are open here atm) you ll see trades updating **live**, I went to firebug to the Net tab and there was no updates... so I wonder how are they doing that? 
I can see there is a streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com that actually makes fiddler throw an error.

Anyone knows anything else about this live update?

Really interested in this, would really like to know if they are constantly polling , the updates seem to happen at irregular intervals

found some info [here](http://blog.underdog-projects.net/tag/streaming-api/) 
Please note my interest is on the seeminly **push** aspect of it ( ie view is updated when there is new information)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called Comet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

It is a comet system using a hidden iframe technique.  A step by step description of what is going on with streamerapi as well as a simple debug HTA to consume the feed is available on my site: [AJAX Push – Comet](http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=204).